# How to load javascript files conditionally using Gulp

Tags: javascript, gulp

I'm currently searching to load my javascript files with conditions on my project. They are minified into one file a gulp task. But all of them are loaded at the same time (libraries and all others specific scripts).

I'm looking for a way to load only scripts I need for the current page.

For example I want:

Page /product : needs jquery.js, main.js, product.js, similar_products.js
Page /user : needs jquery.js, main.js, user.js

And of course creating a task for every page is not a solution.

I know how to do it on Assetic, but I need to find how to deal with it on Gulp.

Comment: will each page include different script bundle?